# partial from a folder

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I'm working along with Railscast 407 (it's a pro/paid episode) where Ryan Bates adds public activity functionality to a site, namely, each activity (create or update recipes or comments on recipes) is displayed in a public feed. At one point in creating the app, he uses the code below to render out a partial from the /views/activities folder, however, he also adds a comment subfolder so the create partial path is like this `views/activities/comment/_create.html.erb` and the link to it is like this

```
<%= render "activities/#{activity.trackable_type.underscore}/#{activity.action}", activity: activity %>



<h1> Activities </h1>

<% @activities.each do |activity| %>
    <%= div_for activity do %>
    <%= link_to activity.user.name, activity.user %>
    <%= render "activities/#{activity.trackable_type.underscore}/#{activity.action}", activity: activity %>
    <% end %>
<% end %>
```

I'm pretty certain I copied his code correctly, but I'm getting this error when I try to follow along, which

```
The partial name (activities/comment/) is not a valid Ruby identifier; make sure your partial name starts with a letter or underscore, and is followed by any combinations of letters, numbers, or underscores.
```

However, he doesn't get that error in the episode. Here's a screenshot[image]  Here's a screenshot of his directory[image]

Fyi, the actual partial at this stage of the episode looks like this

```
commented on <%= link_to activity.trackable.recipe.name, activity.trackable.recipe %>
```

Can you explain why this isn't working for me?

Comment: `activity.action` is most probably nil which causes the error

Comment: first check if "activities/#{activity.trackable_type.underscore}/#{activity.action}" is returning the path as you expected. I believe it should be something like "activities/#{activity.trackable_type}/_#{activity.action}", but not sure :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

At one point in the episode, Ryan Bates sets the default action to nil in the method that tracks activity (in the application controller)

```
  def track_activity(trackable, action = nil)
    current_user.activities.create! action: action, trackable: trackable
  end
```

However, he later changes the default to the parameter action like this

```
def track_activity(trackable, action = params[:action])
    current_user.activities.create! action: action, trackable: trackable
  end
```

If you use the former code, then unless you explicitly declare the action, it'll be nil in the db, and then the view code in the OP will trigger the error. Therefore, it's safer to use the second version of track_activity.

Thanks to comment by @jvnill for pointing this out